# Handle google play services cloud save correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-cloud-save

I am trying to make an implementation of the google play services cloud save for my game. My game has a shop where you can buy items and level them up. Everything works but I am unable to make great code design.

The problem comes with the frequency of the save. If I save the game each time that the player level up an item (which can happen several times in less than 5 seconds) the data usage of the app will increase by a lot and that is something that the user doesn't want.

If I save the game every X seconds, it could happen that the user level up and item, close the app and the game is not saved.

If I save offline and synchronize the save game file with the online part. If a user log-in with a different user, the game data will be messed up since it will synchronize the offline data of User 1 with the online data of User 2 ( This can happen for example, if two users share the tablet)

I can't see any way to save to the "cache" part of the google play save or something similar.

How do you correctly handle this situation?

Comment: What about doing it in [`OnApplicationQuit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html), [`OnApplicationFocus`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html) and  [`OnApplicationPause`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html)

Comment: AFAIK OnApplicationPause/Quit is not guaranteed to be executed if killed by the user/ OS so you could have some problems if you use that. Please correct me If I am wrong

Comment: That's true .. but ;) That's what the others are for .. e.g. usually the User can't even actively kill the app without at least causing the `OnApplicationFocus` to be called since he first has to open the "Task Manager" thingy which already un-focuses the app. So you could probably make your saving everytime the app is about to lose focus (`void OnApplicationFocus(bool hasFocus) { if(!hasFocus) { /*save progress here*/ } }`)

Comment: And finally you also need the `OnApplicationPause` due to `On Android, when the on-screen keyboard is enabled, it causes a OnApplicationFocus(false) event. Additionally, if you press "Home" at the moment the keyboard is enabled, the OnApplicationFocus() event is not called, but OnApplicationPause() is called instead.`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The problem with that is that on countries with a low internet connection or if the user has connectivity issues ( he is on a mountain village), he can close the app before the save is committed to the cloud. So it is a race condition, which is not ideal code design.

Comment: Well this would be the case either way .. if your connection is bad this can always happen ... what speaks against writing also as fallback to the device .. include the user so when you open the app again and realize you have a cache file local load that one and try to submit it again ?

Comment: I'm referring to `the game data will be messed up since it will synchronize the offline data of User 1 with the online data of User 2 ( This can happen for example, if two users share the tablet)` .. that is not true if you correctly store and check the logged in user / store to different locations depending on the user

Comment: So it is safe to assume that the UserID will be unique to the app? It is the same for the package name across differents devices?

Comment: If you want to support multiple devices for the same user then a working internet connection is a hard requirement anyway if this is what you were going to ... in this case you shouldn't even allow playing without a connection in the first place or better said if your user causes two async local progresses I'ld say it is his fault and the newer one would probably always overrule the older one anyway .. otherwise you would need some method of "merging" progresses